# how to read the content of PDF file which is opened in the browser

Tags: c#

I have a requirement of reading the content of PDF file from browser using c# and then save it locally. There is no physical existence to that file. It is served when file code is provided using the query string. The sample url is like http://something/ReportStatus.aspx?indvl_pk=12334. I am getting no way to do that. Any help is appreciated. Thanks is advance.

Comment: Do you actually need the browser or would any code retrieving from this http://something/ReportStatus.aspx?indvl_pk=12334 be sufficient?

Comment: I need code for reading the PDF.

Comment: You can use WebClient to download .pdf file with given url to local and use iTextSharp to "read" PDF file.

Comment: I have tried that without success. Incomplete Data is downloaded in corrput format in pdf file. There is no physical existence to file. It is displayed in .aspx page when request is made using query string.